# Pointer trouble with linkedlist implementation

Tags: data-structures, go

Trying to implement LinkedList with simple addToLast function (which adds the new node to the end of the linkedlist) instead of using the inbuilt list)
Below is the code (removed print statements which I used for debugging):

```
package main

import "fmt"

var first *Link
var last Link

func main() {
    AddToLast(10)
    AddToLast(20)
}

func AddToLast(d int) {
    if first == nil {
        last = Link{d, new(Link)}
        first = &last
    } else {
        last.next = &Link{d, new(Link)}
        last = *last.next
    }
}

type Link struct {
    data int
    next *Link
}
```

My understanding of the above code:

Inside AddToLast functions -
After checking if 'first' is nil i.e. it doesn't have any element, 'last' is created 
with 10 as the data and new empty Link as the next. Now 'first' is assigned the same value
as 'last' but using memory address(as reference - I'm not sure if my understanding is incorrect here)

Now when we try to insert 20 (the next new element) the else part in the 'AddToLast' is executed.
'last.next' is assigned a link with value as 20 and it's next as nil. Now 'last' is moved to 'last.next',
to make sure 'last' always points to the last node.

However since I moved 'last' to 'last.next', 'last'('s) memory address changes which is obvious and this also
causes first to point to the new last i.e. with value as 20.

In order to avoid this, I tried declaring 'first' as Link instead of *Link.
However, doing this doesn't make first.next point to new node i.e. 20. I'm confused as to where I'm not thinking correct.

Comment: You said it yourself, you're making `first` point to the same structure as `last`. Therefore anytime you change `last`, it changes `first`. Don't do that.

Comment: Correct, but if I declare `first` as `Link` instead of currently declared as `*Link`. And later when I assign `first` = `last` this would mean that it's a copy and not reference. But doing this leads to the issue I have mentioned i.e. - `first.next` doesn't point to 20 when 20 is added, it points to {0,<nil>}.

Comment: Yes, don't mutate `last` and you won't have that problem.  I'll put it in an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't mutate the element value in `last`, since that element is already created. Make a new `last`, and set the previous `next` pointer to point to it. Here is a modified version: http://play.golang.org/p/-X5RayC0gU

```
var first *Link
var last *Link

func AddToLast(d int) {
    next := &Link{d, nil}
    if first == nil {
        first = next
    } else {
        last.next = next
    }
    last = next
}

type Link struct {
    data int
    next *Link
}
```

Comment: Thank you @JimB. So basically when you do `last = next' you are pointing `last` to the address of `next`. Is that correct? I think using Java has made my pointers more rusty :). Thanks again for your help. It's really nice to see people like you helping out golang community in SO!

Comment: @srock: correct. `last` and `next` are pointers, so `last = next` assigns the address of `next` to `last`.